# WP API users per page

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-json-api, wp-api, rest-api

I've been testing around the v2 of the Wordpress plugin WP REST API in a web app. My goal is to develop an Ionic app.

I've found a problem, though. I've managed to list 100 posts of a custom post type (pronostics) this way:

http://app.lasotana.cat/wp-json/wp/v2/pronostics?filter[posts_per_page]=100

But when I try to list 100 users in the same way it is not working:

http://app.lasotana.cat/wp-json/wp/v2/users?filter[posts_per_page]=100

Is there any way to list 100 users with custom filters?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer all the day but I just found it 10 minutes after posting this question:

To list 100 users, the proper way to use the filter is:

http://app.lasotana.cat/wp-json/wp/v2/users?per_page=100